# Repeat HTML Background-image Only

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, background-repeat

I have this: `<body background="CFIS Fantasy Pool Logo Small.png" bgcolor="333333">`

I want to add a tag so that it repeats on y, so something like `repeat-y`. I have tried many things but it won't work, it just goes all over the screen. What would that whole thing look like if I was to add a `repeat-y` tag. And by the way I want it to repeat on the left side.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with an inline style on the body tag like so:

```
<body style="background: #333 url("CFIS Fantasy Pool Logo Small.png") repeat-y 0 0;
```

But I'd recommend adding it to your stylesheet like so:

```
<body>

body {
    background: #333 url("CFIS Fantasy Pool Logo Small.png") repeat-y 0 0;
}
```

I'd also recommend not using spaces or capital letters in file names as that can cause problems. It's better to do something like this:

```
cfis_fantasy_pool_logo_small.png
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
background-repeat:repeat-y;
```

And for the positioning, use:

```
background-position:left; 
OR
background-position:left top; 
OR
background-position:left bottom;
```